# How to bind a dependency property for a custom control to its view models property

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, viewmodel

I am trying to bind a custom control's dependency property to its ViewModel's property.

The custom control looks like:

---

```
    public partial class MyCustomControl : Canvas
    {
            //Dependency Property
            public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(MyCustomControl));


            private VisualCollection controls;
            private TextBox textBox;

            public string Text
            {
                get { return textBox.Text; }
                set 
                {
                    SetValue(TextProperty, value);
                    textBox.Text = value;
                }
            }

            //Constructor
            public MyCustomControl ()
            {
                controls = new VisualCollection(this);
                InitializeComponent();

                textBox = new TextBox();
                textBox.ToolTip = "Start typing a value.";

                controls.Add(textBox);

                //Bind the property
                this.SetBinding(TextProperty, new Binding("Text") {Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay, Source = DataContext});
            }
   }
```

---

And the View Model looks like:

---

```
-------

public class MyCustomControlViewModel: ObservableObject
{
    private string _text;


    public string Text
    {
        get { return _text; }
        set { _text = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Text");}
    }
}

----------
```

This binding for "Text" Property is not working for some reason.

What I am trying to do is that in the actual implementation I want the text property of MyCustom Control to update when I update the Text property of my underlying ViewModel.

Any help regarding this is much appreciated.

Comment: Show the xaml bindings you are using.

Comment: it seems as though this should work , put a break point in the Text 
Setter

Comment: @eranotzer : I did try putting a breakpoint on the text setter but it never touches the setter in the View, the reason being property not bound to the underlying viewmodels property.

Comment: @MichaelG : there are no xaml bindings in the view because all the controls are generated dynamically. Xaml for the view is very minimal :

'<Canvas x:Name="CustomControlCanvas" x:Class="Controls.MyCustomControls"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
</Canvas>'

Comment: @MichaelG : 
But the xaml where the control is being used looks like : 

'<Controls:MyCustomControl x:Name="myCustomControl" Height="23" Width="150"  DataContext="{Binding MyCustomControlVM}" />'

I confirmed in the code that the control's datacontext property successfully binds to the MyCustomControlVM property i.e. an instance of MyCustomControlViewaModel. 

At this point not able to bind the controls properties to underlying view model's properties.

Answer (score 1):

After some research I finally figured out the problem with my code. I got this code working by  creating a Static event handler that actually sets the new property value to the underlying public member of the dependency property. The Dependency property declaration is like :

```
//Dependency Property
public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(MyCustomControl), new PropertyMetadata(null, OnTextChanged));
```

and then define the static method that sets the property is like :

```
private static void OnTextChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    MyCustomControl myCustomControl = (MyCustomControl)d;
    myCustomControl.Text = (string) e.NewValue;
}
```

this is the only thing I was missing.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Just bind to the dependency property

```
<MyCustomControl Text="{Binding Path=Text}" />
```

Comment: I want to bind the data context to the underlying view model and then I expect my controls property bindings to work. Something like this:   <Controls:MyCustomControl x:Name="myCustomControl" Height="23" Width="150" DataContext="{Binding MyCustomControlVM}" />'

Answer (score 0):

You should bind your member TextBox to your TextProperty instead. I am pretty sure that the binding in xaml on your Text property overrides the one you make in the constructor.